# equivalent characterization of anti-symmetric operator in complex Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $B$ is a bounded linear operator such that $B^* = -B$. In some notes I found the claim that $$B^* = -B \iff \forall h \in \mathcal{H},~ \langle Bh,h\rangle = 0.$$ The author says this equivalence follows by the polarization identity. After spending hours on it I still could not figure out how this equivalence is derived (remark: it is fairly easy to see that the real part of $\langle Bh,h\rangle$ equals $0$ for all $h$ if $B$ is anti-aymmetric, but I do not know how to treat the imaginary part of $\langle Bh,h\rangle$) Thanks!

Comment: Did you look for a counterexample?

Comment: @KeithMcClary what did you mean by that? a counter-example to this claim?

Comment: If $B$ is antisymmetric then $iB$ is symmetric. (I am assuming that you mean $B^*$ is the adjoint of $B$.)

Comment: @KeithMcClary sure. but from $iB$ being symmetric, I can only deduce that $\langle Bh,h\rangle$ has vanishing real part. Still, I cannot deduce the advertised claim.

Comment: It seems to me that the claim is equivalent to: $$A^* = A \iff \forall h \in \mathcal{H},~ \langle Ah,h\rangle = 0.$$